# Find minimum of a function defined via NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I need to find the minimum of a function f(t) = int g(t,x) dx over [0,1].
I used

```
g[t_, x_] := *huge expression*
f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[t, x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

as explained in an old thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474961/find-minimum-of-a-function-defined-by-integration-in-mathematica), but when I run

```
FindMinimum[f[t], t \[Element] Interval[{0,1}]]
```

I get as an answer

```
{0., {t -> 1.}}
```

which is not the minimum, and indeed this is followed by the message

```
FindMinimum::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a saddle point.
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I was trying to keep it short (and similar in notation to the old thread), but the full expressions look like

```
g[t_,q_, u_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{k=OptionValue[k],*other parameters*}, *function of t,q,u,parameters*]
Options[g] = {k -> 3,*other default parameters*};
f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[t, q, u], {u, 0, \[Infinity]}, {q, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 10^5, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]];
```

Comment: **1)** Please provide (some version of) the *huge expression* for `NIntegrate`. **2)** Try using `NMinimize` (with different methods) and see do you get an answer you expect.

Comment: Another idea is to use the principal axis method, which does not use derivatives/gradients.  E.g. `FindMinimum[Abs[2 x - 1] + Abs[x^2 - 1], {x, -2, 2}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]`

Answer (score 4):

I will use the definition of `g` given in the answer to question you link to.

```
g[t_, x_] := t^3 - t + x^2
f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[t, x], {x, -1, 1}]
minPt = With[{min = FindMinimum[f[t], t ∈ Interval[{0, 1}]]}, {min[[2, 1, 2]], min[[1]]}]
```

> ```
> {0.57735, -0.103134}
> ```

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point @ minPt}]
```

[image: plot]

This demonstrates that your problem arises from the ill-behavior of your definition of `g`, and since you won't tell what that is, there is nothing further we can say.

Comment: I was trying to keep it short, the expression is long and I'm having trouble to copy paste it because of formatting issues. The only relevant differences wrt yours are:
- I'm using Module[] for default values
- I'm using "QuasiMonteCarlo" to integrate it in f[t_]

Comment: @DavideVenturelli Monte Carlo methods are not very accurate and that may be part of the problem. You better off estimating the minimum from a plot.  Or changing the integration method.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks, I will try with another integration method. Actually it turned out much faster than others for producing plots... btw, how can one have Mathematica read off the minimum from a plot automatically? I will have to do so varying some of the other parameters involved, and this would already be a solution:)

Comment: @MichaelE2 nope, I tried to change method but unfortunately the problem remained (thanks anyway!)

Comment: `Max@Cases[
  Plot[Sin[20 x]/2 - Cos[x/2], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All],
  Line[pts_] :> pts[[All, 2]],
  Infinity]`.  It should be accurate to a few digits, but you don't have much control over it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 that's great, thanks a lot! I implemented it with the option PlotPoints -> 50 in the function Plot[] to speed up the evaluation - the more points, the more accurate it gets. You saved me really a lot of work.

Comment: @DavideVenturelli You're welcome. Raising `MaxRecursion` (above the default `6`) might be better for more accuracy than raising `PlotPoints`.  It causes more sampling where the curvature is greater, and at ordinary extrema ($|f''(c)|>\epsilon>0$), the curvature tends to be greater.